# incoming ACCEPT all iptables rule still appearing

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm following this guide here: http://isalazyadmin.net/2009/07/02/configuring-a-basic-firewall-for-debian-linux/

And I have the iptables listed shown, but my server still appears to be accepting all incoming connections (ie: bittorrent peers are still connecting, even though I didn't allow those ports).

/etc/iptables.rules

```
*filter

# This will allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8
# that does not use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  This accepts all already established connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# This allows all outbound traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# This will allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere, this are the normal
# ports used for a web server
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow bittorrent/rtorrent ports, from ~/.rtorrent.rc
## -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8071:8079 -j ACCEPT


# Allow ICMP ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# Reject all other inbound traffic
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

When I run iptables -L after a reboot, I still get this as my first rule:

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Not sure where this is coming from.

Here is the full list:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Here is the output of iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6701:942626]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8927:989420]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3281:284415]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9:720]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1758:148908]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1758:148908]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6701:942626]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6701:942626]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8928:989684]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8928:989684]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jan 11 09:54:19 2013
```

Here is the iptables -vL output:

```
$ sudo iptables -vL
[sudo] password for ettinger: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8303 1206K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  !lo    any     anywhere             loopback/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
  12M 7191M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
   18   980 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
    7   344 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
  379 22728 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
18316 1110K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:8071:8079 
 120K   15M ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:6881 
24809 1489K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9001 
  688 35244 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9030 
  874 73072 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
12705  871K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  14M   12G ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Haven't you noticed your first INPUT rule `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere`?

Comment: It seems that rules aren't loaded at boot time. Make sure that you added "pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules" line to your /etc/network/interfaces file (as author of tutorial suggests)

Comment: @ott : it concerns lo inteface only, so it's ok

Comment: Can you redo your listing with `iptables -vL`?

Comment: Your rules and your post boot state actually do match up, that is not the problem -- see my answer ;)

Comment: I added iptables -vL output.

Answer (score 17):

The line you are worried about:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

is actually because of this in your rules:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Notice the interface is explicit in the rule, but not in the `-L` output.  Move that rule to the middle of the list, use `iptables-restore` and notice the "ACCEPT all -- anywhere" has moved down too.  Now try changing the rule a bit:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

and the `-L` output will become:

```
target     prot opt source                 destination  
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost.localdomain  anywhere
```

"localhost.localdomain" will be your 127.0.0.1 hostname from `/etc/hosts`.  This at least makes it clearer where that rule came from.

You can also see more detailed information including the interfaces with `iptables -vL`.

BTW, you may want to start your rules:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
```

Drop everything by default as a fall through for safety.  This is considered bad manners, however (see the link in Gilles comment below), so you may want to create a final catch all for each table which uses `-j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-prohibited`.

Comment: FYI, `iptables -vL` will show the full rule, including the interface. So it'll eliminate confusion like this.

Comment: Thanks @derobert -- I had forgotten about that display.  Will edit this into the answer!

Comment: Regarding dropping everything by default: [Reject IP packets with an ICMP error, or just drop them?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/reject-ip-packets-with-an-icmp-error-or-just-drop-them)

Comment: @derobert +1 on `-v` switch. My firewall rules don't look as bad as I thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a matter of completeness, in order to avoid this problem in future use the `-v` verbose command line option when displaying the table. As thus:

```
iptables -Lv
```

The output should now include the interface it affects in the "in" and "out" columns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  151 13073 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
  126 33414 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in this part of INPUT chain:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

especially in the last line. Everything after this line is unnecesary, because this line accept everythink.

You have to delete this line from the rules by this command:

```
iptables -D INPUT 1
```

You have to inspect your firewall rules, where is rule, which adding this line.

Comment: "ACCEPT all  --  anywhere anywhere" comes from this rule: "-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT" so it's concerns only lo interface, so it's not the issue.

Comment: I deleted everything, but it still shows up with iptables -L

Comment: ok, that's what someone else mentioned. thanks. I can safely ignore it.

Comment: @chovy: your rules are ok. Issue lies in restoring it after reboot. Try follow this steps: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/445